# Chef - share libraries between cookbooks

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Is it possible to reuse the code from a cookbook library in another cookbook provider/library?

cookbook1/libraries/lib.rb

```
    ...
    def very_useful_check
      true
    end
    ...
```

cookbook2/libraries(providers?)/foo.rb

```
...
myvar = very_useful_check
...
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible by using [Chef Libraries](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_libraries.html).

make sure the functions are defined in your namespace via ruby modules:

```
module Foo
  def very_useful_check
    true
  end
end

class Chef::Recipe::namespace
  include Foo
end
```

Then you can use it in any recipe like:

```
myvar = Foo.very_useful_check
```

Comment: What is the ::namespace for?